# Cannot compile Qt examples using MSVC 2019 with prebuilt Qt 2017 MSVC components

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, qt5, visual-studio-2019

1. Qt Creator version 4.10.0
2. **MSVC 2019** with C++ Desktop workload and IDE installed
3. Debugging binaries from Qt installed
4. Qt 5.13.1 **MSVC 2017 (32/64 bit**) and UWP (32/64 bit) pre-built components installed

Qt **detects compilers** for MSVC 2017 32 and 64 bit (green ticks no yellow box) but not for UWP. I have Qt Visual Studio Tools extension installed but not configured yet. When I try to compile any example from Qt Creator, I get `C1083` error saying `<stddef.h> was not found`. It is included in `<cstdlib>`. I read somewhere that this is due to non-compatibility between 2 and 4.

Comment: I think possibly it is necessary to recompile Qt on MSVC 2019 which will be tedious.

Comment: The components are called “prebuilt for MSVC 2017” for a reason.

Comment: @scopchanov I did also read somewhere that MSVC 2015 and 2017 are not binary-compatible but 2017 and 2019 are.

Comment: Visual 2015 Update 3, Visual Studio 2017, and Visual Studio 2019 are binary compatible, but you should see [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=vs-2019) for the details of what that means.